# How to bring back the default banner image in LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin

I had changed the default banner image in my LinkedIn profile to a custom image. Now I want to bring back the default banner image. How can I do that?

Comment: I have tried to realized how to do, but to be honest I didn't find any way out,
My advice is **working-around**, go to google image and search to **"background image in linked-in"** after that you can provide to upload image found in your profile :) [Click here](https://www.google.pl/search?biw=1440&bih=803&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=7QIyW7L6LY-QmwWu6ZWoCA&q=background%20image%20in%20linkedin&oq=background%20image%20in%20linkedin&gs_l=img.3..0i24k1.5046.5046.0.5450.1.1.0.0.0.0.103.103.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.1.102....0.NyW-8CT2Kvc#imgrc=j_aaRoyPlQwNMM:) for linked-in image

Answer (score 1):

Delete the custom banner image you have added.

Follow the below instructions from [LinkedIn Help](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/49960/adding-or-changing-the-background-photo-on-your-profile?lang=en) to delete the background photo:

> To reposition, delete, or change a background photo:
>
> 1. Click the **Me** icon at the top of your LinkedIn homepage.
> 2. Click **View profile**.
> 3. Click the **Edit** icon in your introduction card.
> 4. In the **Edit intro** pop-up window, click the **Edit** icon on the top right corner of the background photo, and choose one of the following options:
>
>    - **Reposition** to drag and reposition the image (option available on the image itself).
>    - **Delete** photo to remove the image.
>    - **Change** photo to change the current background photo.
>
> [image]
>
> 5. Click **Apply**.
> 6. Click **Save**.